# while clicking down arrow cursor need to come other control

Tags: vb.net

[image]

i given code like this:

```
Private Sub txtemployeename_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtemployeename.KeyDown
        keyval = e.KeyData
        Dim keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys = e.KeyData
        If keyData = Keys.Down Then
            LstEmployee.Visible = True
            LstEmployee.Focus()
        End If
    End Sub
```

while i am cliking down arrow first time that is not focusing to listbox,second time am clicking down arrow that is focusing..also once cursor come to tha list box,if i clik enter that should be displayed in text box..for that i given code like this..

```
Private Sub LstEmployee_Enter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LstEmployee.Enter
        txtemployeename.Text = LstEmployee.SelectedItem   
End Sub
```

but this is not working properly..for loading list box i given code like this:

```
 Private Sub txtemployeename_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtemployeename.KeyPress

        Dim s As String = txtemployeename.Text
        LstEmployee.Visible = True
        loadlistbox(LstEmployee, "select  Ename from EmployeeMaster_tbl where Ename LIKE'%" & s & "%' ")

    End Sub
```

Comment: You want to select from this list with `up` and `down` key?

Comment: i want to select using down key

Comment: Could you please be more clear about the objects being exactly involved and what you want to accomplish? For example: LstEmployee is a combobox and txtemployeename is a textbox; I want to display in the textbox this and that every time I...

Comment: Inventing your own ComboBox is almost never not a mistake.  You cannot get good help that assists you with using ComboBox to solve your problem if you don't explain why you avoided it.

Comment: sir,,,LstEmployee  is a list box,if i given any letter in the textbox list box will load with names matching with that letter

Comment: that time i want to use key down to select particular name,,and i click the particular name that should display in my text box..that s all i want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should rely on the `KeyUp event` rather than on the `KeyDown` one. Also for the `ListBox` you just need the `SelectedIndexChanged` event. Additionally, your code has quite a few errors (wrong query (-> you don't need to call your DB every time to order the items in the ListBox), relies on `SelectedIndex` rather than on `SelectedItem`...). Here you have an updated version:

```
Private Sub txtemployeename_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtemployeename.KeyUp
    Dim s As String = txtemployeename.Text
    LstEmployee.Visible = True

    Dim list = LstEmployee.Items.Cast(Of String)()

    Dim query = From item As String In list Where item.Length >= s.Length AndAlso item.ToLower().Substring(0, s.Length) = s.ToLower() Select item

    If (query.Count > 0) Then
        Dim newItems = New List(Of String)()
        For Each result In query
            newItems.Add(result)
        Next

        LstEmployee.Items.Clear()
        For Each newItem In newItems
            LstEmployee.Items.Add(newItem)
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub LstEmployee_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles LstEmployee.SelectedIndexChanged
    txtemployeename.Text = LstEmployee.SelectedItem
End Sub
```

The code above checks for occurrences (i.e., if the whole string in the `txtemployeename` matches (caps do not matter) the starting substring of, at least, one element in `LstEmployee`) every time a new character is introduced in `txtemployeename`. The ListBox is updated with these ocurrences. `txtemployeename` displays the name of the selected item in `LstEmployee`.

I hope that this will be enough to help you to build the code required to deliver the exact functionalities you are after.

NOTE: bear in mind that this approach (deleting/adding `Items`) is incompatible with cases where the ListView is populated with a `DataSource`. If you rely on a DataSource you would have to update this code accordingly.

NOTE2: the proposed approach deals with the elements in the ListView. You have to introduce these elements at the start from whatever source you are using; this code only updates  existing information (items in the ListBox). Also bear in mind that this code is expected to be corrected to match your exact requirements; for example: `list` has to be associated with the total number of items (the ones retrieved from your datasource at the start), not with the current ones (as displayed in the code; it just represents a simplified version of the problem): every time a new population occurs all the items (other than the target ones) are deleted and thus the ListBox does not represent a reliable source. Example to understand this: at the start, you have "aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc"; if you type "a", all the elements except "aaaa" would be deleted. If you type now "b" and consider the actual elements in the ListBox, no change would occur as far as the only element is "aaaa"; you would have to consider all the original elements (which, as suggested via comment, might be stored at the start in an array/list of strings).

Comment: in previous am loading list box using this query:select  Ename from EmployeeMaster_tbl,,now how i can load the listbox with proper employee name

Comment: @user2603688 one thing is populating the list from a datasource, for example from DB + query, as you are doing; and a completely different story is dealing with the collection of objects in the ListBox. My "query" is just considering the elements in the listbox, not your database. If you want to perform the ordering/population from your DB you would have to deal with it directly via SQL, but I do think that the proposed approach is better/quicker. In your case, instead of clearing items and adding them one by one, you can set the generated list (newItems) as the new datasource.

Comment: @user2603688 I mean... you have to populate the listBox from the DB at the start but for all the new populations (every time a string is introduced in the textbox), you don't need to connect to the DB again, just deal with the items you introduced at the start. The best thing would be storing all these items in an array/list and bring it into consideration while using Dim query = From item... that is, Dim list = will NOT be the current items in the listview, but the initial ones you got from the database (stored in a list of strings).

Comment: @user2603688 please, take a look at my updated answer, I hope that everything will be clear enough this time. Also bear in mind that, although the proposed code, is (virtually) directly applicable to your problem, this wasn't my intention. I have made my answer as generically applicable as possible: you want to update the items in a listBox on account of certain input and display the selected item in a textbox and there you have the solution; you will have to adapt this code/ideas to your specific situation.